# Run Jest tests only for current folder

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I have Jest installed on my machine and typing `jest` from terminal results in tests from parent folers also getting executed. I want to run tests only from the current folder.

For e.g. if I go to `c:/dev/app` in terminal and type `some-jest-command`, it should only run files with `.test.js` present in the `app` folder. Currently, running `jest` command from `app` folder runs tests in parent folders too, which is not my desired behaviour.

Comment: What utility do you use to call jest, `npm`? What is your `package.json` config for jest? And where is located your `package.json`?

Comment: I am using npm. There is no special config for jest in package.json, which is located few directories above the folder in which I am running jest tests.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By default, Jest will try to recursively test everything in whatever folder `package.json` is located.

Let's say you're in `c:/dev/app`, and your `package.json` is in `c:`. If your basic command to invoke Jest is `npm test`, it'd recursively check for all tests in `c:`.For a specific folder like mentioned before, try running `npm test dev/app`.

Comment: Just a clarification on the answer, first argument that can be passed to jest is directory. When setting up IDE's you can pass target directory such as 'dev/app' as cli argument to Jest

Answer (score 77):

If you want to run the tests from a specific folder user the --testPathPattern jest flag. When setting up the npm script add the path to the folder as well. In your package.json add the flag in you npm scripts. Check the bellow code for an example.

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "test:unit": "jest --testPathPattern=src/js/tests/unit-tests",
    "test:integration": "jest  --testPathPattern=src/js/tests/integration"       
    ....
},
```

If you want to watch as well for changes, use the `watch` flag:

```
{
  ...
  "test:unit": "jest --watch --testPathPattern=src/js/tests/unit-tests",
  ...
}
```

After that open, the command line, change the directory where your project is and run the unit test.

```
npm run test:unit
```

or integration tests.

```
npm run test:integration
```

Comment: testPathPattern doesn't appear in the docs for Jest 27.0 :/

Comment: @RonaldC check again https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#options

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathpatternregex

Comment: the parameter `--watchAll` is irrelevant in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 15):

To only run testing in a specific directory and to coerce Jest to read only certain type of files(my example: 'ExampleComponent.test.js' with new Jest version @24.9.0 you must write exact "testMatch" in jest.config.json || package.json in "jest" part next `"testMatch": [ "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/**/*.test.js" ]`,
This testMatch in my case hits all files with the prefix .test.js in **tests**/subdirectories/  and skips all other files like 'setupTest.js' and other .js files in '**mocks**' subdirectory which is placed inside of '**tests**' directory,so,my 'jest.config.json' looks like this

```json
    {
        "setupFiles": [
            "raf/polyfill",
            "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^.+\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/**/*.test.js"
        ]
    }
```

Just adapt to your needs 'testMatch' regex.

A little note: This is for jest@24.9.0 && enzyme@3.10.0 if it matters to anyone.

I hope it will be useful to someone, cheers all.

Answer (score 1):

From the root of your project, you can run `jest <substring of files>` and it will only run the test files which have the substring you added.

```
$ jest /libs/components
> [PASS] /libs/components/button.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--package.json

"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }

--jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    "testMatch": [
        "<rootDir>/tests/unit/*.test.js"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

yarn:

```
yarn test nameoffolder
```

npm:

```
npm test nameoffolder
```

---

For example, if you have a folder named `widget` and you only want to run the tests in the `widget` folder you would run this command.

yarn:

```
yarn test widget
```

npm:

```
npm test widget
```

Comment: For me, npm test did not work because the script **test** was missing/not known. What worked for me was:  `npx jest widget`

Answer (score 0):

You can always target a specific `describe('...` clause, if your test file of interest contains a unique describe, you can run jest with the `-t` option.

Say I have the following test file:

```
...

describe('folder running text XYZ', () => {
    it('test A', () => { ... });
    it('test B', () => { ... });
    it('test C', () => { ... });
    it('test D', () => { ... });
});

...
```

You can target the test set above using the following command: `jest -t "folder running test XYZ"`.

`-t` docs:

```
-t, --testNamePattern        Run only tests with a name that matches the regex pattern.
```